# Reading Registry String Values into List

Tags: c#, registry

I have a registry key location that appears as the following:

[image]

I'm looking for C# code that will allow me to enumerate all REG_SZ values in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Test\Windows Update\Exceptions so that I can add them to a list. I have found examples of how to read a specific value (the RegistryKey.GetValue method) when you know the explicit path, but in this case I will need to read in all values under the "Exceptions" key without knowing what the value names will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RegistryKey.GetValueNames()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvaluenames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should give you the list you are looking for. You can then iterate through the returned names, and call [`RegistryKey.GetValue(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvaluenames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get each's value. For example:

```
foreach(valueName in exceptions.GetValueNames())
    myList.Add(String.Format("{0} is {1}", valueName, exceptions.GetValue(valueName)));
```